# Workbench deploy

Tags: deployment, workbench

I have retrieved the unmanaged package using workbench from one org and have to deploy the that in another org . 
I'am directly deploying the retrieved package by just logging into another org using Workbench but the user which was present in the org I retrieved from is not present in the org in which I will deploy.

Does this create an error while deploying using Workbench because I am facing the same error while deployment?

Answer (score 2):

Any metadata that references a user, such as assignment rules, won't deploy correctly if that user isn't present in the target org.

To correct this, you can unzip the metadata and manually update each entry to point to a user that does exist in the target org.